# Android OpenGL responsiveness

Tags: android, opengl-es

I made a simple android application, which renders a square using openGL. The square can be moved using your finger. It works fine, but while moving the square around you can feel a considerable input lag, especially when doing circular motions. Are there any tricks to reduce or mask this lag?

Here's the code:

```
public class InputTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new InputTestView(this));
    }

    public class InputTestView extends GLSurfaceView {
        private InputTestRenderer renderer;

        private float prevX;
        private float prevY;

        public InputTestView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            renderer = new InputTestRenderer();
            setRenderer(renderer);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                renderer.moveEye(prevX - x, prevY -y);
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                prevX = x;
                prevY = y;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public class InputTestRenderer implements Renderer {
        private final float[] verts = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
        private final int nrOfVerts = verts.length / 3;
        private FloatBuffer vertBuf;

        private float eyeX;
        private float eyeY;

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) { 
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            gl.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verts.length * Float.SIZE / 8);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertBuf = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
            vertBuf.put(verts);
            vertBuf.position(0);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glOrthof(-width / 2, width / 2, height / 2, -height / 2, 1, 100);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            synchronized (this) {
                gl.glTranslatef(-eyeX, -eyeY, -10);
            }
            gl.glScalef(200, 200, 1);

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuf);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, nrOfVerts);
        }

        public synchronized void moveEye(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            this.eyeX += deltaX;
            this.eyeY += deltaY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the code should be quite fast. The only thing that might cause the lag could be the synchronized translation you do (or the onTouchEvent, but in this case it shouldn't cause any lag, it could possibly cause a kind of stuttering). Try removing the synchronization and see if it improves matters.

Comment: Removing synchronized blocks did not decrease the delay, I also tried setting the rendering mode from CONTINUOUS to WHEN_DIRTY but that didn't help either.

Comment: Maybe it is the device that is slow at rendering?

Comment: Rendering speed is ok, I tried this on multiple new devices, they all act the same (rendering is fast, but the input is delayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect your UI thread and your rendering thread are fighting for CPU time.  Try adding this line to onSurfaceCreated() :

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
```

Reducing the renderer's priority ensures that motion events get processed a bit more promptly. Seems to make a difference.

FWIW I dislike GLSurfaceView's design and prefer to aim for a set framerate, usually 50, using Handler.postDelayed() to schedule each frame to be drawn at 20ms intervals.

Comment: Changing the thread priority did not make a visible difference. But could you explain how exactly can I use anything other than the GLSurfaceView for openGL rendering?

Comment: On a Nexus S running ICS it definitely seems to make a difference. Re GLSurfaceView, look at the source code for it. You can create a variant of it that also extends SurfaceView and does EGL setup, but which doesn't use a dedicated rendering thread.

Comment: I'll look into it, perhaps I can get a better performance using the NDK.